# Twitter Feed is auto refreshing

Tags: bugs, twitter, moto-x

This has been happening for a while and I'm finally trying to fix it. Whenever I open my twitter application, it always auto refreshes the timeline feed. If I haven't checked it in a while, it automatically goes to the top of my feed. I've tried clearing the data, uninstalling, even switching phones. Does anyone know whats going on? If not, are there other suggestions for twitter clients?

Comment: I believe this is the default behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

This is what twitter is supposed to do, it's not a bug, however if you want to try some other twitter clients here are some (Paid and Free)

[Talon for Twitter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.klinker.android.twitter) - Paid

[Carbon for Twitter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dotsandlines.carbon) - Free

[Plume for Twitter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.levelup.touiteur) - Free

Comment: Correct and +1 but I just want to add that apps like Carbon are only allowed 100,000 tokens for Twitter and tend to fill up quick as people don't know to drop the token if they aren't using the app anymore so you may have that issue with some apps.

Comment: @RossC It's pretty annoying, I wish twitter would loosen up a bit, they can still insert sponsored tweets into your feed so I don't know why they aren't more supportive towards 3rd party clients